# IIS Client Certificate Auth, IIS logs pairs with error code 0 0 64

Tags: ssl, iis, authentication, internet-explorer-11

I've got a windows server 2012R2 machine running IIS that is set up to require client cert authentication.

When I try to connect from a remote host in the same sandbox, I get the dreaded 'Page can not be displayed'.  Additionally, chrome reports the following reason code: ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY

Unlike this post:

[IIS 7.0: Why does Require Client Certificates cause error 500 and "page cannot be displayed"](https://serverfault.com/questions/160809/iis-7-0-why-does-require-client-certificates-cause-error-500-and-page-cannot-b)

I don't see 500.0.64 in the logs, but rather 0.0.64.  I see two logs entries witht this for each request.

I've verified that the client cert i'm using is trusted and I have the private key for it.  What else could be causing this problem?

===Update===

The 0 0 64 errors don't necessarily come in pairs.

I'm running IE 11 on the server, trying to connect to a local website.

FailedRequestTracing is enabled but logging nothing for these errors.

===Update 2===

I also wrote a much longer write up of my issue on the IIS forums 
https://forums.iis.net/p/1233652/2125255.aspx?IIS+Logging+0+0+64+error+code+when+using+client+certificate+authentication+oneToOneClientCertificate+

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this some time ago, although not in a satisfying way:

As part of our IIS security hardening process, we removed all unused or unnecessary modules.  After this process was complete, these weird errors stopped, and connectivity to the websites worked without any further issues.

So, basically, some module was mucking up the requests.  I'm sorry I can't pinpoint the one it was.